# how to use internationalization using spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

if any user visit my site can able to view my site in different languages,so i had selected 3 languages English,french,Tagalog.by using Spring internationalization, i had coded,but when i click on french or Tagalog link language not changing to either of then but still remains in English.the program is compiled and run without any error but language is not changed to french and Tagalog respectively.
if any info is required i'm ready to provide.

[project view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z80mo.png)

**messages_en.properties**

```
student.title=Student List
student.id=Student ID
student.firstname=First name
student.lastname=Last name
student.year=Year
```

**messages_fr.properties**

```
student.title=Liste des étudiants
student.id=carte d'étudiant
student.firstname=prénom
student.lastname=nom de famille
student.yearLevel=Niveau année
```

**messages_tl.properties**

```
student.title=Listahan ng mga Magaaral
student.id=Numero ng magaaral
student.firstname=Pangalan
student.lastname=Apelyido
student.yearLevel=Antas
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- Spring Internationalizations -->   
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**student.jsp**

```
<title>Student Management</title>
</head>
<body>
Language: <a href="./?language=en">English</a> | <a href="./?language=tl">Tagalog</a> | <a href="./?language=fr">French</a>
<h1><spring:message code="student.title" /></h1>
<form:form action="student.do" method="POST" commandName="student">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="student.id" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="studentid" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="student.firstname" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="student.lastname" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="student.year" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="year" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><div class="col-md-12">
                 <input type="date" class="def-input" placeholder="Your Date of Birth!">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <th><spring:message code="student.id" /></th>
    <th><spring:message code="student.firstname" /></th>
    <th><spring:message code="student.lastname" /></th>
    <th><spring:message code="student.year" /></th>
    <c:forEach items="${studentlist}" var="student">
        <tr>
            <td>${student.studentid}</td>
            <td>${student.firstname}</td>
            <td>${student.lastname}</td>
            <td>${student.year}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing defaultLocale parameter with another value ("fr" by example) to check if it works.

If it's not working then check your folder structure and verify that in this line :
`<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />`

the classpath link to the right place because the spring-servlet.xml must reach the messages.properties files to run correctly.

Comment: i'm providing work-space path InternBridge\com\internbridge\resources. with in resource folder .properties files are present. are u asking this or some thing else.

Comment: Yes, that what i'm looking for...so try to create a messages folder into resources and replace value="classpath:messages" by value="classpath:messages/messages"

Comment: i had edited the answer, please once click on project-view link on top, in this, under resource i'm creating normal folder named messages but it is created as package view, why this is happening?. i had kept .properties files in it, it is not working.please do help me.

Comment: Try to create your folder at the same level as the Webcontent folder. Do it directly in your workspace and not in the IDE. Then refresh your project.

Comment: even though i had created in work-space, folder seems like package and language remains in English not changing to other languages, it is not working.please do help me